# Get url of the web app

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Spreadsheet, with the google-app-script, we can get the spreadsheet id by:
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()

On the other hand, how to get the url of the web app in the spreadsheet?
With that, I can show the url in some cell of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var webAppUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
```

You will find the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service